# Need help modifying https redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I have a Debian 9 VM with nginx as my web server and have the following in my config.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Now, if I navigate to example.com or www.example.com, then it redirects to https://www.example.com.

However, if I type the following in the address box or similar: `example.com/site/about`, then it tries to redirect to `https://example.com/site/about` (without the www) and Chrome and Firefox warn me that the site does not have a certificate for that link.

I am using CertBot. The server config for it contains:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
```

How can I get `example.com/site/about` to redirect to `https://www.example.com/site/about`.

I believe initially, I had an if condition and a regular expression, but I saw a tip on nginx website to simplify https redirects and am using the above code.

Comment: You don't have a server_name without the www so it isn't found

Comment: @ShawnC. OK, I added a block for without www. and set the redirect to https//www.$host$requesturi. Would that be correct?

Comment: `$host` is set to the host name in the request. If you want to use the value from the `server_name` directive, use `$server_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this variation of nginx server:

```
   server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.example.com example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

It returs https url with www. Also, if you have access to your name servers, you could do CNAME record which redirects no-www to www.

Comment: Please consider adding a short explanation to your answer. StackOverflow is a site to help people further in their skills, and not just a codesharing platform. Leaving an explanation helps them understand how to solve the problem. :)